# How can I turn off the built-in subversion repository in Xcode 4?

Tags: svn, repository, xcode4

I use a third party app to handle my SVN code repositories and so would love to have Xcode 4 stop asking me to use its native repository control every time I open a project.  While it looks like you can start a new project without using the built-in version control, I have yet to find a way to turn off this (annoying) feature with old projects already under external version control. Anyone had any luck?

Comment: As a workaround you can block outgoing connections to your svn host with Little Snitch.

Answer (score 3):

Renaming the IDESubversion.ideplugin file that is inside XCode.app to IDESubversion-DISABLED.ideplugin worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can go to File > Source Control > Repositories, and just remove all the repositories you don't want controlled by Xcode. Then, close your project and reopen it.
Unfortunately, that will only last until you quit and relaunch Xcode :(

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, that's exactly the problem: once you reopen a project in Xcode, it tries to setup the repository again.  So my question is how to prevent that permanently.

Answer (score 1):

It's on a per-project basis.
In your project, goto File / Source Control / Hide Remote Status. Next, in Organiser, goto Repositories and delete the project's repo.

Did this for a couple of projects which were crashing due to (null) values being assigned to some file's SVN details in Xcode (the remote repo was unaffected). They've been (touch wood) more reliable since.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent Xcode 4's Subversion integration from running for all of your projects, you can move the plugin at `/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin` to some other place.

Comment: I have 4.2.1 and removing or doing anything to the above mentioned plugin cause Xcode to refuse to run, and states that I must re-run setup again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but am looking for the same answer.  Xcode4's subversion is feature devoid, am sticking to versionapp.

Answer (score 0):

For XCode 4.5, I was able to turn off the subversion plugin by doing the following:

```
sudo mv /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin.DISABLED
```

Answer (score -4):

Recursively delete all the .git or .svn folders.

Comment: I suppose if you no longer want source control, but this seems like a very bad option!

Comment: I tried that on a copy of my project. This will give you a warning "missing .git directory" forever